# Windows batch script to Shell script

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, batch-file, shell-script

I have a Windows batch script that I want to run on Linux, but I'm having trouble converting it to a shell script

I wonder if anyone can help.

```
:start
for /r %%F in (*.mkv) do (
C:\Python27\Scripts\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe  -y -i "%%F" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 4.5M -bufsize 9M -c:a ac3 "%%~dpnF.mp4"
if not errorlevel 1 if exist "%%~dpnF.mp4" del /q "%%F"
)
TIMEOUT /T 60
goto start
```

I've been trying to convert it to a shell script, but I'm having trouble. I'm not great at this.

```
for f in {*.mkv,*/*.mkv,*/*/*.mkv,*/*/*/*.mkv}; do 
ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 4.5M -bufsize 9M -c:a ac3 "${f%mkv}mp4";
rm "$f";
```

I'm not sure how to loop it, so its constantly checking.

Comment: The "Linux script" term is incorrect. It's "shell script". Please add the name of the shell that you're using and edit the tittle.

Answer (score 0):

More like (assuming bash):

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.mkv
do 
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -minrate 4.5M -maxrate 4.5M -bufsize 9M -c:a ac3 "${f%mkv}mp4";
    [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && rm "$f";
done
```

In practice:

- You were missing a `done` statement indicating the loop
- Your `{*.mkv,*/*.mkv,*/*/*.mkv,*/*/*/*.mkv}` pattern while not incorrect will make ffmpeg issue an error message for each pattern that doesn't match. `globstar` together with `**` makes a single pattern work across directory levels.
- I added a test at the end to erase the .mkv only if there was no error when transcoding to mp4.

Comment: Thanks ill give this a try and get back to you thank you, how would go about running this constantly so it constantly checking for mkv's from the top level directory

Comment: im getting this error in when running it [matroska,webm @ 0x43468c0] Format matroska,webm detected only with low score of                                     1, misdetection possible!
Truncating packet of size 1336371 to 152
[matroska,webm @ 0x43468c0] EBML header parsing failed
ffmpeg/ffmpeg/tests/ref/lavf-fate/av1.mkv: Invalid data found when processing in                                    put